# Installing k3s: zsh: not enough directory stack entries

Tags: k3s

When I install k3s, I'm getting

> zsh: not enough directory stack entries.

You can see this at the bottom of the log below,

```shell
$ curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
# Check for Ready node, takes ~30 seconds
sudo k3s kubectl get node
[sudo] password for user: 
[INFO]  Finding release for channel stable
[INFO]  Using v1.25.7+k3s1 as release
[INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.25.7+k3s1/sha256sum-arm64.txt
[INFO]  Downloading binary https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.25.7+k3s1/k3s-arm64
[INFO]  Verifying binary download
[INFO]  Installing k3s to /usr/local/bin/k3s
[INFO]  Skipping installation of SELinux RPM
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/kubectl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/crictl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/ctr symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating killall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh
[INFO]  Creating uninstall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh
[INFO]  env: Creating environment file /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service.env
[INFO]  systemd: Creating service file /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service
[INFO]  systemd: Enabling k3s unit
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/k3s.service → /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service.
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s
zsh: not enough directory stack entries.
```